# file() PHP function , what is the max upload size to not crash the server when the conversion of the file to array is happening?

Tags: php, file, server

I'm using file() function to turn for example a .txt file into an array and the work easy with it. What I want to know is if there is some sort of file size limit (which I'm sure is) when we convert a txt file into an array. What is this limit? Should I check the filesize before applying the file() function over it? I just don't want to crash the server when someone uploads a 1MB file and then this file to array convertion will create a big server crash.

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule. There's a memory limit for the amount of memory your server has and that PHP is allowed to use, but that translates to how much is being stored in your array, than how large the file is. There is also the file size upload limits allowed by PHP and Apache, but those will give errors and won't crash the server.

Comment: Ye I understand this , but mainly I want to know if the usage of file() function over a 1MB file for example and it's conversion into an array will make my server crash...?

Comment: What is the error message of the crash?!

Comment: It is very unlikely that you'll "crash the server". Instead, at worst you'll probably just crash that specific request or process. That said, do you _expect_ to receive such giant files? Have you tried testing anything? PHP has a memory limit built into it that will in theory guard you, so you might want to look at tuning that.

Comment: The only way the server would actually crash, as opposed to just the process, is if you completely max out the memory (too many requests doing that same process at the exact same time) or the disk fills up from too many large files.

Comment: Ok I understood pretty much what's going on . Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: If you're concerned that loading an entire file will cause a problem, don't do it. Read the file line by line and process it without storing it in an array. This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score -1):

When you put a file content or query result or ... into an array there will be no limit except the memory that is assigned to PHP processes in the `php.ini` file. For example:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Some part of this assigned memory is dedicated to the PHP itself and the rest can be used for loading content as you mentioned. As far as I know, there will be no crashes in loading file content into the array. For example, sometimes 20MB of query results are stored in an array so why converting a 1MB file into an array could be a problem?!